# how do i run phpunit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/master/tests

My familiarity with phpunit is pretty lacking.  How do I run those tests?  I installed phpunit using the following commands (per [this website](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/installation.html)):

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

I try doing `phpunit MD5Test` from the tests/Crypt/Hash directory and get the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Crypt_Hash_TestCase' not found in /root/phpseclib/trunk/tests/Crypt/Hash/MD5Test.php on line 9
```

That's not too surprising since Crypt_Hash_TestCase isn't included anywhere.  There's a bootstrap.php file but I don't know how to use that either.

Comment: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/index.html

Comment: So your proposal is that I spend days and days reading the manual, learning all about how to write unit tests and utilize such obscure functions as assertContainsOnly() when all I want to do is run a unit test?  Gee...  thanks.

Comment: Why not? I did, so did many others. You are allowed to read _some_ of the manual, the bits about actually running unit tests may be useful.

Comment: Ok...  http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html That's the only example I found of running phpunit.  I assume *.php is appended to ArrayTest but if so then what do the contents of ArrayTest.php look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run phpunit from this directory: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib
The clue is that that is where the the phpunit.xml.dist file is found.

To run all tests you start it with simply:

```
phpunit
```

If you just want to run the MD5Test tests then (still from that same root directory):

```
phpunit tests/Crypt/Hash/MD5Test.php
```